# Cloudflare purge cache by prefix is not working

Tags: caching, cloudflare, prefix, hostname, purge

I need some help with Cloudflare, I'm not being able to purge the cache using the prefix option. For example if I go to Cloudflare portal and go to Caching section -> Purge Cache -> Custom purge, then I select Prefix and put something like this [www.myexamplesite.com/mypath](http://www.myexamplesite.com/mypath). Nothing happens, the only option that is really purging the cache is by hostname and in that case I have to use [www.myexamplesite.com](http://www.myexamplesite.com) but that's not a good option because it affects so many pages.

Does anyone know if there are "common" reasons for failing the cache purge by prefix? I haven't found any clue about the issue, so if you have any idea it could help to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar frustrations that in the end came down to capitalization.

The cache is case-sensitive and prefix matching is also case-sensitive. My solution was to purge all of the most common capitalizations that people might use for the given folder. You can have up to 30 prefixes per purge request, so it wasn't too bad to have it purge:

[www.mysite.com/mymainfolder](http://www.mysite.com/mymainfolder), [www.mysite.com/MyMainFolder](http://www.mysite.com/MyMainFolder), [www.mysite.com/MYMAINFOLDER](http://www.mysite.com/MYMAINFOLDER)

Any of those references that aren't used in your system won't have anything to purge anyway, so the extra clearing is not a performance problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In my case the solution was to purge the cache using the cache-key, as I'm using the Cache API to store the info in the cache the normal way doesn't work. Now, we still use the option by prefix but instead of using the url with the path, we use the cache-key.